# Generating random numbers in C

Tags: c

I know this question has been asked time and again. I need random numbers between 0-9. I am using the following code:

```
srand(time());
int r;
for (;;)
{
    while(condition)
    {
        r = rand()%10;
        // ...
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now I am getting the same sequence of numbers for each iteration of for loop. Can someone provide me the correct code?

PS - My compiler doesn't recognize `arcrandom()`.

Comment: Can you post your full code? There are lots of errors in this code, and you have obviously missed out some "unimportant" parts that might actually be the cause of the problem. If your code is too long to post, try to reduce it to the simplest example that reproduces the error.

Comment: If you "know this question has been asked time and again", why do you ask it once more instead of looking up one of earlier answers?

Comment: I looked up all the solutions but couldn't find a convincing answer. Why is everyone so emotional about this question. I have never got so many views so quickly ever!!

Comment: I think you're just seeing it that way. Few people here are emotional. Please, post your real code so we can solve your real problem.

Comment: "I am getting the same sequence of numbers for each iteration of for loop" ... What loop? The inner `while` loop, the outer `for` loop, some other loop you aren't showing?

Comment: @pmg the for loop. "I am getting the same sequence of numbers for each iteration of FOR loop"

Comment: What happens if you remove the call to `srand()`? (That's the same as calling `srand(1)`)

Comment: @Peter: sometimes the small space for comments (well, now it's 600 chars, but we still tend to be short :) makes it difficult to convey tone, so I wouldn't say anyone is being emotional here.

Comment: Is all this stuff in main? You're so close :) Just post a compilable example, like Mark suggested. If we can take your code directly and compile it to get the same problems its much easier to fix.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This problem stems from the fact that on some implementations the lower-order bits of rand() are not very random. Quoting from the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand):

> "If you want to generate a random integer between 1 and 10, you should always do it by using high-order  bits, as in
>
> ```
> j = 1 + (int) (10.0 * (rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0)));
> ```
>
> and never by anything resembling
>
> ```
> j = 1 + (rand() % 10);
> ```
>
> (which uses lower-order bits)."

Comment: @Peter: Well, I can't help you then... You're probably doing something else wrong that you didn't notice and didn't copy into the example code you posted. There seems to be nothing else wrong with it.

Comment: You're probably right Martinho. I will look at my code again. Thank you for the answer

Comment: Are you calling srand once, and only once at application startup ? do not call srand more than once.

Answer (score 7):

You're probably calling this function within the second, and `srand` is going to get seeded with the same second. You should only call `srand` once at the beginning of main.

Comment: A solution might be to use another seed source, such as a higher resolution timer.

Comment: In the code `srand` is called only once and not inside the loop. That does not make the sequence repeat every iteration

Comment: Martinho, you know this how? It's called once *inside the function it resides*, which may or may not be `main()`.

Comment: @GMan: it's not called *inside* the loop, so it won't repeat every *iteration*

Comment: You're correct. But you made the claim "srand is called only once", which can't be determined from his code. Consider: `void foo() {/* his code */} int main() {while (true) foo() }`

Comment: Okay, the only once assertion was a little unfortunate. I meant only once withing the context of the code posted, and not once during the application lifetime.

Comment: I mean, Bruce is still correct to say `srand` should be called only once at the beginning of main. Otherwise problems will arise. It just won't cause the problem posed here.

Answer (score 2):

Many [pseudorandom generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) have an observable period. 
 If you need a long period consider using the algorithm from [Knuth 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming). 
It has a period of about 2^55, and is simple to implement.   
[RANARRAY](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/programs.html)

Comment: The lower-order bits of rand() do have a short period. But the OP says that working around that doesn't solve the problem...

Answer (score 1):

Remove all `srand()` calls from your code.

Add **one, unique** call right before the first statement in `main()`.

```
int main(void) {
    int foo = 42;
    int bar = baz(42);

    srand(time(0));
    /* rest of your program */
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
srand(time(0));

r = rand() % (max+1);

//r will be a random number between 0 and max.
```

I can only think that you did not initialize correctly, or your redacted code is redacted wrongly.

Comment: Oops! `rand() % max+1` is different than `rand() % (max+1)`.

Comment: Durrr! That's what comes of fast typing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't compile -- `for()` is not valid C.

Are you **sure** that you are calling `srand` only once, at the start of the program and before any `rand` calls?  Calling `srand` within the loop would explain this behavior.

Comment: The for loop has a condition inside it.It is not relevant to my question...Yes I am calling srand() only once, before any rand calls

Comment: @Peter: if it is not relevant, you can write it as `for(;;)` which is valid and won't upset anyone.

Comment: My bad..I didn't mean to upset you

Answer (score 0):

Have you random()?

[random() man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/random)

I have made simple program:

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<40;i++)
printf("%d",rand()%10);
```

And geting 7938024839052273790239970398657627039991 - no repeating here.
How long is your sequence?

Answer (score 0):

The only possible way you could be getting the *exact* same sequence of numbers is if there is a call to srand() somewhere in the code that you haven't shown us.  It could be deep within a function call somewhere.

The **proper** way to fix this would be to find the extra call to `srand` and remove it.  However this quick hack might get you started:

```
static int seed = time();
int r;
for (;;)
{
    srand(seed++);
    while(condition)
    {
        r = rand()%10;
        // ...
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements for statistical randomness you might find it better to ditch the psuedo random number generator and try an external source.

[random.org](http://www.random.org/integers/) and [randomnumbers.info](http://www.randomnumbers.info/content/Download.htm) (amongst others) will provide truly random numbers for download, which [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/) should handle for you.